# magento 2.1 custom theme header minicart layout overriding not working

Tags: magento-2.1, module, layout, header, mini-cart

I am building a new theme in magento 2.1. I need to override the default header minicart of magento 2.1. For that I had copied

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html
```

and pasted it in

```
app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html
```

But Whatever change I make it in the content/html in my custom theme, it is not affecting in my website. I have deployed the static contents and cleared caches. Still no result. Can any one please help me to find out where it gone wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just run upgrade command first and then run deploy command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run below command to work your file,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Clear cache and also clear browser cache.**

Thanks.